After filtering, replace multiple columns to constant value and another column
I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks like:



Row
Source
Location
Campaign
New Campaign
some other columns




1
s1
l1
c1
nc1
...


2
s2
l2
c2
nc2
...


3
s3
l3
c3
nc3
...



and there is a (boolean) condition crit which is a mix of some rules based on some other columns. What I want to achieve is:
If the condition crit is met (for a row):

Replace Source, Location by constant x and y.
Replace Campaign by New Campaign.

For example if row #1 and #3 match the condition, desired output is:



Row
Source
Location
Campaign
New Campaign
some other columns




1
x
y
nc1
nc1
...


2
s2
l2
c2
nc2
...


3
x
y
nc3
nc3
...



Currently, I am doing this in 2 steps, firstly
df.loc[crit, ['Source', 'Location']] = ['x', 'y']
then
df.loc[crit, 'Campaign'] = df.loc[crit, 'New Campaign']
But wonder if there is a way to do it in one go. df.loc[crit, ['Source', 'Location', 'Campaign']] = ['x', 'y', df.loc[crit, 'New Campaign']] throws error.

It is possible to have a single expression, with assign:
df.loc[crit, ['Source', 'Location', 'Campaign']] = df.loc[
    crit, ['Source', 'Location', 'New Campaign']
].assign(Source='x', Location='y').values

or the DataFrame constructor:
df.loc[crit, ['Source', 'Location', 'Campaign']] = pd.DataFrame(
    [['x', 'y']] * sum(crit), index=df.index[crit]
).join(df[['New Campaign']]).values

variant:
df.loc[crit, ['Source', 'Location', 'Campaign']] = pd.DataFrame(
    [['x', 'y']] * sum(crit),
    columns=['Source', 'Location'],
    index=df.index[crit],
).join(df['New Campaign'].rename('Campaign'))

Output:
   Row Source Location Campaign New Campaign some other columns
0    1      x        y      nc1          nc1                ...
1    2     s2       l2       c2          nc2                ...
2    3      x        y      nc3          nc3                ...

